# How to get row count from backendless tables using angularjs

Tags: backendless

Need to display row count in html page.I need to get it from backendless.
I am very new to backendless, I don't know how to write Query to get row count from backendless table using angularjs.

Thank you.

Comment: http://support.backendless.com/topic/query-result-with-only-the-row-count

Comment: where to set pageSize to 1

Comment: query options (i have no knowledge of an angular SDK but I guess it's the same or you're using REST)